# Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind doesn't work with FileUpload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I'm creating the following functionality: create table on button click using data from the excel file which was loaded and save this table to xml file. After saving I want to show modal window (bootstrap) with some message. Window managed by javascript function and I called this function from the code behind.

This is my HTML page:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="modalSaved" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                Changes were saved successfully!
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" runat="server" id="ok" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="file">               
      <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="OpenFile" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
    </div>

    <div id="actions" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="CreateRepBtn" runat="server" OnClick="CreateRepBtn_Click" />
      <asp:Button ID="SaveToXml" runat="server" OnClick="SaveToXml_Click" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       function openModalSaved() {
           $('#modalSaved').modal('show');
       }
    </script>

  </form>
</body>
```

And C# code with calling the javascript function:

```
protected void SaveToXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /* save to xml code */   
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModalSaved();", true);
}
```

The problem is that modal window doesn't appear. I supporse it is connected with FileUpload element somehow because on another page without FileUpload such code works perfect.

I've also tried to use UpdatePanel (FileUpload element was outside) but it doesn't help.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Any suggetions are welcome.

Comment: Why don't you set #modalSaved's runat attribute to server and then control its visibility directly from code behind

Comment: Try RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of RegisterStartupScript.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I've replaced the script block before all page elements and tried this: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModalSaved();", true). But it doesn't help unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void SaveToXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "$(function(){openModalSaved();});", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For various your solution may not work, change a bit the implementation and remove script registration from button click callback.

Add in markup hidden placeholder containing client script with call of openModalSaved at document ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openModalSaved() {
           $('#modalSaved').modal('show');
        }
</script>

 <asp:PlaceHolder id="plhFileUploaded" runat="server" Visible="false">
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            openModalSaved();
        });
        </script>
    <asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void SaveToXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /* save to xml code */   
   plhFileUploaded.Visible = true;//this will render your placeholder contacting the script
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, check for console errors or something, to see if you event click    is working just put in placeholder script <asp:PlaceHolder id="plhFileUploaded" runat="server" Visible="false">
 <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(0);
        </script>
    <asp:PlaceHolder>  if no alert is present after save then you have a problem with bottom callback, debug your code and see what happens on page_load and button_click events :)